# What is the advantage to using images instead of actual radio inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, cross-browser

What advantage could there be for Amazon to use images of radio inputs as opposed to actual `<input type="radio" />`? Is this a browser compatibility solution perhaps?

[image: radio button]

[image: HTML for "button"]

I have never seen `<input type="image"... />` either (second line of the code). How can an image be an input?

And I threw in the javascript tag because that's what's being used to update their state.

Comment: radio inputs are hard to style consistently in different browsers, but images look about the same everywhere. image inputs are the same as normal submits or buttons.

Comment: `type="image"` is legit (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type-image-keyword) but not necessarily being used as originally intended here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of an image is purely for style consistency sake, as styling an input is very hard to maintain cross-browser.

Also, this particular input is not an exact replacement for a radio button, but rather Amazon is using a [image submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html) to gather what the user has selected. Likely, once you click on one of these options, a form is submitted or another function is triggered.

Comment: Is this a common practice? I only noticed it because the image was sort of low resolution. Maybe it's a good practice. I've tried using custom css/javascript radios before and it's always been kind of annoying.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's common practice, as I do not see it to often. Actually, the only case I can recall off the top of my head is from Amazon. I'm not sure if its just a constant that they use in their development, but I know that Amazon sends out support survey emails with "forms" in them, have radio buttons that are really just images wrapped with a link. And they look exactly like these radios. Maybe they just use images across the board when making this style of radio button.

Answer (score 1):

They use images because they know exactly how it will render on all browsers, and there is virtually zero discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

By using custom images, there is less cross-browser incompatibilities.

Therefore, when they have a customer on the phone, for example, they don't have to find out how a button looks in Internet Explorer compared to Google Chrome.